# How to avoid MSVC warning C4701: potentially uninitialised local variable

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have some cross-platform code, which I've whittled down to this:

```
int bar(char **p) {
    *p = "hello";
    return 1;
}
void foo(int n) {
    int x = 0;
    char *p;
    if (n) x = bar(&p);
    if (x) if (p) return;
}
```

Compiling this with GCC 7 gives no warnings. Compiling this with MSVC gives two warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c foo.c
$ cl /Wall /c foo.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.15.26730 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

foo.c
c:\cygwin64\home\kyz\foo.c(9) : warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'p' used
c:\cygwin64\home\kyz\foo.c(9) : warning C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'p' used
```

If `n` is non-zero, p is initialised. If `n` is zero, `p` is not initialised but `if (x)` and the default zero value of `x` ensures `if (p)` is never reached.

How can I tell MSVC to suppress this without either changing compiler warning levels, or initialising `p` to a dummy value?

FWIW, I [reported this to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/363489/c4701-false-positive-warning.html), maybe they'll fix it in a future compiler. It's a tricky problem and [they're in good company](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=may%20be%20uninitialized)

Comment: Maybe this isn't your real code, but I suggest `if (x && p) return;` instead of `if (x) if (p) return;`.

Comment: I know this is a reduced example, but I don't see why `NULL` is a "dummy value". The warning is also not without merit, I'd say. 6 months from now, someone, maybe even yourself, changes `bar` in a way that breaks your real function.

Comment: The example is reduced from [this](https://github.com/kyz/libmspack/blob/master/libmspack/mspack/chmd.c#L539). I want provable use-before-initialisation to fail compilation, but I don't want "potentially" use-before-initialisation false alarms. Initialising `p` would suppress ALL use-before-initialisaion analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would initialize the pointer to NULL, and move on with my life.

If you don't want to change the warning levels, or put in [warning pragmas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) to suppress it just there, you can change it globally under properties.

```
(properties)

(c/c++)

(advanced)

enter 4701;4703 in the "Disable specific warnings" area.
```

To disable a warning in msvc in-line in the code:

```
// Save warning levels, and drop it to level 3 
#pragma warning (push, 3)

// turn two warnings off
#pragma warning (disable : 4701 4703)

// screwy code goes here

// restore original warning levels.
#pragma warning (pop)
```

In-line warnings are useful to enable you to drop the warnings around the microsoft include files, then jack them back up again for your own code.

Comment: You had me at "warning pragmas". What warning pragmas could I use to suppress this warning in these lines of code in MSVC?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't see that `if (x)` can't be entered unless `if (n)` is entered, in which case `p` is assigned to via the function call.

Most compilers don't perform that deep of an analysis (that what static analyzers  are for), so it sees a possible code path for `p` to be read without being initialized.

Perhaps the best way to handle this is to restrict the scope of `p` to where it is used:

```
void foo(int n) {
    int x = 0;
    if (n) {
        char *p;
        x = bar(&p);
        if (x && p) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or initialize `p` to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that `n` may be zero (i.e. due to a call like `foo(0);`) so here

```
    if (n) x = bar(&p);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
           Not executed if n is 0
```

`bar` may not be called. In that case `p` will be uninitialized when used here:

```
   if (x) if (p) return;
              ^
              Uninitialized if n is 0
```

as the compiler most likely won't track the value actual value of `x`.

You could do:

```
   char *p = NULL;
```

to get rid of the warning.

Comment: `x` is initialized with `0`, though. To be frank, I don't see how this answers the OP's question. This answer seems to completely ignore the content of the question.